# how to solve the error: "Value after * must be an iterable, not int" as shown in the image below

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

how to solve the error: "Value after * must be an iterable, not int" as shown in the image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN1Dh.png)

Comment: `'len` function return length of the iterable not another list and you are unpacking it , which is not true, if your want to join in do like this `markers = ",".join(["?",len(valeur_1[0])])`

Comment: Please post code as _text_, not as an image.

Comment: I don't think you want the `,` before the `*...`. The line should just be `markers = ", ".join("?" * len(valeur_1[0]))`

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to unpack an... integer :)

The asterisk operator in python is used to unpack a list, for example if you have some case like:

```
full_name = ["Jimi", "Hendrix"]
print("My name is", *full_name)
```

So in your case you passed an integer, while the operator expects an iterable such as list for example.

Answer (score 0):

Join takes one argument if want to give more than one argument you can give it as list or tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you're trying to accomplish l. You are trying to put `?` for each field in `valeur_1[0]` (I know some french ).

In that case you should use this

```py
markers = ",".join([ "?" for _ in len(valeur_1[0]) ])
```